# Petrol mower for the one reason that it can be left outside, but I don't really like petrol powered devices

Tags: lawn, lawn-mower

I currently have a small, lightweight and inexpensive electric lawn mower for my small garden. I have to carry this mower down to the cellar after every use. This makes the house dirty as the cellar is not accessible from the outside.

Now I'm thinking of buying a petrol lawn mower and just leaving it outside. I live in Western Europe, can a gasoline lawn mower be left outside all year round? What should I look out for when buying a winter-proof petrol lawn mower?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want to store your electric lawnmower outside?

Comment: generally because electronics break down in rain and moisture. I use a lawnmower with a power cable

Comment: I leave mine out all Winter in New Jersey, well below freezing. Unplugged.

Comment: I would imagine that an electric lawnmower (with battery taken inside) would fair better then a petrol one as there are less moving parts and less to go wrong.  I'd imagine that either would encourage blades to rust though.    I assume your area is to big to use a weed trimmer?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not trying to be funny but my neighbor keeps his mower and trimmer outside all year round. They work for a few years then he has to buy a new one.

I suggest a tiny shed or small packing crate for your mower.  Just enough to cover it from rain or snow.

If you keep a gas mower outside all winter you should add gas stabilizer to the fuel tank in the fall.  Gasoline has a lifetime of three to six months but your mileage may vary depending on how well it is sealed and temperatures.

Alternately you could buy a cordless electric mower and just bring the battery inside in the winter.

Comment: A dog house for your lawnmower, basically, unless you have use for a larger shed. +1 A gas mower will likely prove more of a maintenance hassle, and would also need protection from rain/snow to have much chance for long-term reliability.

Answer (score 2):

> I live in Western Europe, can a gasoline lawn mower be left outside
> all year round?

It certainly can be, yes.  It is not much different from a car or other engine driven machine living outside.

> What should I look out for when buying a winter-proof petrol lawn
> mower?

I would want a mower that:

- Had a manual that told me how the manufacturer wants me to winterize the mower, with a procedure I am willing to follow.  Is draining the carburetor too annoying to actually do it?
- Minimized complexity - no power drive, blade break clutch, heated handle bars, etc.
- Minimized the numbers of fluids in the machine (2 cycle, if available)
- Was a size and shape I could store *and cover* through the winter.

I want to emphasize the cover, it will minimize condensation.
[image: Lawn mower peeking out from under a beige cover.]

Surprisingly, an electric lawn mower already meets my criteria pretty well.  The machine is simple, there is no gasoline, lubricants are usually sealed and not serviceable anyway, and the minimal electric circuitry will survive, just like the electronics in a car survives winter.