How to find weatherproof lawn mowers? This is my main purchase decision criteria, but can't find products in online shops
ChatGPT tells me there are weatherproof lawn mowers, they are also called "outdoor lawn mowers". You can store them outside all year round (don't put them in the cellar). I will also buy an additional cover.
This is my killer purchase criterion, plus a medium-power engine (longer grass can be cut without any problems). I have checked a lot of Swiss online shops and cannot find such a category/description in the products. Can you tell me how I can find a weatherproof lawn mower for about 400-500$. How should I search? Are there any popular models where you can't go wrong as newbie?

I wonder what ChatGBT says indoor lawn mowers are for.  Shaggy rugs?

@MackM sufficiently large greenhouses filled with grass, perhaps?

And this is why AI answers aren't to be trusted.   The only people who can effectively mow in the damp are full sized tractors mowing the local park.

An AI chatbot (recently) has told people to 'eat a small rock a day' and that parachutes are no more effective than backpacks for jumping out of planes if you wish to survive. It also suggested putting some Elmer's glue in pizza sauce to prevent the cheese from sliding off. I really worry about how far from reality the claims around AI are and how many people may suffer from not realizing how smart they aren't.

Over on History.SE we've banned using the output of an AI as the basis for the confusion behind a question. If an AI says something that's inconsistent with anything else you know, you should just assume the AI is wrong/delusional (yet again), and go on your merry way.

ChatGPT is hallucinating (if you don’t know what that means when talking about AI, I highly encourage you to take the time to read the linked Wikipedia article, the concept is really important when dealing with AI in general and LLMs in particular). There is no special category of lawnmower that is ‘designed’ to be stored out in all weather conditions. The very nature of what a lawnmower is means it has to be designed to handle outdoor conditions reasonably well, or it won’t function well as a lawnmower.
Provided you have a proper cover for it and are not in an especially metal-hostile environment like a beach, storing a lawnmower outside year-round should not significantly reduce it’s life expectancy. For battery electric mowers, this notably does not include the battery (keep that inside when not using it), but other than that even those should be fine outside in most conditions. This also assumes of course that you perform regular seasonal maintenance (sharpening the blade, keeping it properly clean, etc), which will have a much bigger impact on long-term longevity of any yard equipment than storage conditions.
Of course, you should secure it against theft somehow if this is your plan for storage, but that has essentially nothing to do with the choice of lawnmower itself.

With mains electric mowers, the plug is probably the worst part to get wet - normal mains plugs in any country I've been to aren't even properly splash-proof and  many could fill with water.  Kept upright the mower body should have some protection against rain blowing under whatever is sheltering it and into the electrics

In reality, there is no such thing as a weatherproof lawnmower that can be stored outdoors all the time, whatever ChatGPT says; all will deteriorate over time. Electric mowers particularly should not be stored outdoors - see here.

I can't quite agree with that article.  "However, electric mowers - both corded and cordless - must not be left outside. Water damage can break these mowers beyond repair." is all I see they say about it, but my electric mower is on its 6th season of outdoor life.  I just had to be careful to harden it off :-)

@MackM please write a detailed answer about " I just had to be careful to harden it off :-)" I am very interested

Sybil - I think you'll find 'hardening off' the lawnmower is tongue in cheek... We can harden off plants, but not mowers...though I'd be interested to know if its kept under some sort of shelter and whether they live in a dry region...

@Sybil I just keep the lawn mower under a cover like I mention in your other question: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/65709/petrol-mower-for-the-one-reason-that-it-can-be-left-outside-but-i-dont-really

@Bamboo It is under a lawn mower cover up against the wall of the house in a region that sees about 40 inches of rain per year.  So, semi-sheltered.

My $50 corded electric lawnmower is about to turn 8 and has been outside continuously since its original purchase, with no shelter except being kept under a tree.

I would expect an electric lawnmower to be more resistant to being stored outside as long as you keep the battery indoors.  Moisture is really bad for gas engines. If I were to go back to gas mowers (why?) I would only put pure gas with no ethanol in it.
